# Verify that javascript request is from website

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, csrf, tracking

I am creating something like intercom.io and mixpanel. The user visits a website - there the admin can insert a js snippet - the js calls the server via ajax and logs a visit or some other form of data.

So far so easy, i would like to ensure that the request is made from the website so the admin has to include a unique public key. But it is of course not safe on the website. I read something about csrf protection with cookies and headers but for this the user has to have cookies enabled. And if the user does not have cookies enabled the tracking will not work, although i will not force tracking, e.g. accept the do-not-track header etc.

**So how can i ensure that the request is made from my async loaded script and not some command line with a fake referer without cookies?**

Comment: Never heard of it before but thats what i was searching for! If you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JWT (JSON web tokens) for the request authorization.